# is it possible to find width of an object using camera in Ios?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, camera

i wanna measure the distance between iphone camera and the object showed on the screen and want to find a width of an object by putting two point on the screen.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/orthograph-architect-3d-cad/id464252559?mt=8

in this application when we put the two point on the screen then it will calculate the distance between two point.

any suggestion for finding distance, width & camera angel ?

Comment: i think you need to learn Augmented Reality iOS:

Comment: Eight up votes, yeah, right - I smell some fishy voting ring.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use following api link ti achieve this and detailed tutorials and documentation provided in that. But it will take time to get through that. I used in my android app and found out the distance between two objects in Augment reality

[iqEngines](https://www.iqengines.com/smartcamera/)

Happy Coding !!!